# React native variable not update inside function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

```
  const [businessHour, setBusinessHour] = useState("");
 const getHour = () => {
   console.log(businessHour);
}

setBusinessHour('1234');
getHour();
```

The result show "" instead of "1234", any way to update the variable ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

please update your entire code of a component. The result will show empty string `""` first, and then when state is changed, it will print `"1234"`. so there will be multiple logging instead of just one.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem earlier. My workaround is to create a temporary variable to use because the state has not updated yet.

```
const [businessHour, setBusinessHour] = useState("");
 const getHour = (businessHour) => {
   console.log(businessHour);
}

let newBusinessHour = '1234'
setBusinessHour(newBusinessHour);
getHour(newBusinessHour);
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do is  , use the useEffect callback :

```
const [businessHour, setBusinessHour] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
getHour()
},[getHour])

 const getHour = useCallback(() => {
   console.log(businessHour);
},[businessHour])

setBusinessHour('1234');
```

so here basically `useEffect` will be called whenever `getHour`  changes which is dependent on `businessHour`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can update state if you want to update some views followed by that state.
In the case above, you don't need to update state.

```
businessHour = '1234';
getHour();
```

Then you will get the result you want.